# Application icon not showing after Gradle plugin update to 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

I want to upgrade my Android Plugin for Gradle from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1. I could fix all the errors following the [Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio). My problem now is that on Android Nougat (24) and Android Marshmallow (23) application icon is replaced with the default robot icon.

Could you help me find the reason for the problem. Previously icon was shown and I don't see logical reason why not now.

I tried all suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776933/android-application-icon-not-showing-up) without success.

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
...

<application
    android:name="...Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/application"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon,theme,label,allowBackup">

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="...SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/application"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

...


</application>
```

Here is project Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
}
}

allprojects {
ext {
    androidApplicationId = 'myapp.android'
    androidVersionCode = 1
    androidVersionName = "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}
```

Comment: did you check what is available as a resource against this value 'ic_launcher_round'

Comment: I updated my android studio without your problem, I think you should clean your project.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I checked the icons and they are my app icons as expected.

Comment: @salman Cleaning does not help. I tried many times.

Comment: dod you any specific folder for marshmallow or naugat for mipmap images if yes please check in there as well weather you have the required images or not there as well

Comment: I haven't added any specific folder for the versions.

Comment: Is the value of the `android:replace` attribute correct? I would have thought you'd need an `android:` prefix on `theme`, `label` and `allowBackup` as well?

Comment: It's correct. I tried with and without "android" prefix. It always works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in this [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/androidstudio/status/875311569219006464). "Android plugin 3.0.0 enables AAPT2 by default" as explained in the [Migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio#aapt2). Looks like that this change causes problems with the resources.

To fix application's icon I had to disable the use of Aapt2 by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties` file.

**NOTE:** I could NOT reproduce the problem when I created new application with the same gradle setup.

Comment: android.enableAapt=false no longer works, as aapt2 is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

I also wasted about 2 hours on this. The brute force solution was to create a stand-alone project and copy my assets over. From there, I spotted the solution:

[image]

Android Studio now defaults to **mipmap-anydpi-v26**. Previous I had **mipmap-anydpi** only, which worked prior to updated the gradle to 3.0+.

Hope this helps.

Comment: saved my life, thank you! Android Studio 4.1 still has this "error".

Answer (score 1):

Android system would never show the icon for the application until you do.

Using [tools:replace="attr"](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) like you did here -> `tools:replace="android:icon,..."` Will replace the icon in the higher-priority manifest, and keep the icon in the lower-priority manifest.

Comment: The "replace" is needed to resolve conflicts during manifest merging. Here is explained the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506800/android-studio-gradle-icon-error-manifest-merger

Comment: @MarioKutlev Maybe if you have a sub resource with the same name in sub-project (ic_launcher) that you implemented in your dependency will occur that issue. 

A random solution is to rename your launcher icon.