# How to change Android icon everywhere?

Tags: android, icons

I am trying to change the app icon in my app in Android Studio. I replaced all `ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round` images in all their respective folders. The icon changed in the app menu, however, when I press the square button in my phone (the one to clean cache and remove all applications) it still appears the default icon.

[Link to an example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a48D1.jpg)

I don't know where else that icon may be inside my project. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your manifest you should change icon sources, change round-icon to what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776933/android-application-icon-not-showing-up/60023889#60023889

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android application icon not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776933/android-application-icon-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to change launcher icon using asset studio in Android Studio. You have information how to do it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) in official documentation. Also it's good to use vector image and add it through Asset studio.
Also, be aware that after adding new icon, launcher on Your phone could have it cashed, so restart Launcher app or You phone (depends on what launcher You use, for example Nova Launcher have restart option in settings).
When designing icon stick to official [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) to make Your icon adaptive.

Comment: Great! I created the icon using asset studio and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i did the same and it's work on React native project, try to clean , rebuild and check your AndroidManifest.xml
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

android:label="@string/app_name"

android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"